# How to click on button and start javascript with HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I am trying to create a bot with HtmlUnit to get some products from a website automatically, I am getting to list the products, but the site has several branches and for me to change to the branch I want, I need to change the value of a select and click on a button, but after I click the button, I have the same page as before, it does not change anything and it does not return any error or warning, does anyone give me a hand?

```
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("url");
        final HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("s-ch-select-city");

        select.setSelectedAttribute("8", true);

        ScriptResult resultFinal = page.executeJavaScript("document.getElementById('s-ch-change-channel').focus()");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
        synchronized (page) {
            page.wait(10000);
        }

        Page pageResultFinal = resultFinal.getNewPage();
        HtmlPage pageCascavel = ((HtmlPage) pageResultFinal);
```

Comment: You might want to try [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) with headless chrome/firefox, it works better than HtmlUnit on complex websites

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to the page i can only guess.

Try to replace

```
Page pageResultFinal = resultFinal.getNewPage();
```

with

```
Page pageResultFinal = page.getEnclosingWindow().getTopWindow().getEnclosedPage();
```

And check to log for any errors.
Additionally i think doing the js stuff is not required. You can do something like

```
page.getElementById("s-ch-change-channel").focus();
```